# Oracle INSERT data from variables

Tags: oracle, sql-insert

I'm looking for some help with Oracle.

I have a query like this

```
SELECT column1 FROM table1 WHERE column2 = 'columndata';
```

in my query, this result returns multiple rows.   I would like to use the results in multiple insert statements in the same query.

ps. my actually query for the SELECT statement is large and complex.

i.e.

```
INSERT INTO table2 values (data from previous SELECT);
INSERT INTO table3 values (data from previous SELECT);
INSERT INTO table4 values (data from previous SELECT);
INSERT INTO table5 values (data from previous SELECT);
etc etc...
```

How can I accomplish this using variables?  p.s.  I can't use temp table due to permissions.

I've tried searching google but I'm not getting the results I need.
thanks
Craig.

Comment: try to use dynamic sql using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Comment: thanks @ilsurealism.  But I cannot figure out how to handle multiple rows.. the fetch returns lots of rows which in turn need INSERTED in to numerous tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need an `INSERT ALL` statement, e.g.:

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO table2 (col1, col2, ...) VALUES (source_col1, source_col2, ...)
  INTO table3 (col1, col2, ...) VALUES (source_col1, source_col2, ...)
  INTO table4 (col1, col2, ...) VALUES (source_col1, source_col2, ...)
  INTO table5 (col1, col2, ...) VALUES (source_col1, source_col2, ...)
SELECT source_col1,
       source_col2,
       ...
FROM   ...;
```

You would need to amend the list of columns being inserted to and from accordingly, obviously.